# Jquery: Appending a String to a textbox in gridview

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, append, datagridviewtextboxcell

I have a gridview column of type text.

```
<sjg:gridColumn id="vName" name="variableName" index="variableName" title="Variable_Name" sortable="true" editable="true" edittype="text"/>
```

I want to append a string "C:\" to the dynamic textbox contents. How do I do it?
I tried using this Script but it is not Working

```
var myString="C:\";
$('#vName').append(myString);
```

Comment: Could you please post code you tried and doesn't work?

Comment: Can you post your HTML code.I mean code which is generated after running the application.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply setup a custom format function:

Inside the colModel of the column

```
   ....
   formatter: CustomFormatFunction, unformat: CustomUnFormatFunction},
   ....
```

Custom Format Functions:

```
function CustomFormatFunction(cellval, opts, rowObject, action) {
   return "c:\" + cellval;
}

function CustomUnFormatFunction(cellval, opts, rowObject, action) {
   return cellval; //or manipulate the string to remove the "c:\"
}
```